# Were the warriors who were killed in the Mahabharata war revived for one night?

Tags: mahabharata

I read somewhere that a heroic warrior killed in the Mahabharata war was revived for one night. Is it true? Who was he?

Comment: Only warrior who was stay alive even after his head was chopped away was Balbarik (grand son of Bhima).

Comment: @TheDestroyer can you unlock the question? I think he is asking about the warriors brought back to life after the war. It occurs I think in the Ashwamedha Parva.

Comment: @Surya are you talking about that part where Vyasa shows Kauravas, Karna etc... to Dhritarastra, Gandhari etc.. by his divine powers after the war is over... ?

Comment: @Tezz Yes precisely, it has been answered below as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, the dead were revived for one night.

> Vaisampayana said, 'When night came, all these persons, having
>   finished their evening rites, approached Vyasa. Dhritarashtra of righteous 
>   soul, with purified body and mind solely directed towards it, sat
>   there with the Pandavas and the Rishis in his company. The ladies of
>   the royal household sat with Gandhari in a secluded spot. All the
>   citizens and the inhabitants of the provinces ranged themselves,
>   according to their years. Then the great ascetic, Vyasa, of mighty
>   energy, bathing in the sacred waters of the Bhagirathi, summoned all
>   the deceased warriors, viz., those that had fought on the side of the
>   Pandavas, those that had fought for the Kauravas, including highly
>   blessed kings belonging to diverse realms. At this, O Janamejaya, a
>   deafening uproar was heard to arise from within the waters, resembling
>   that which had formerly been heard of the forces of Kurus and the
>   Pandavas. Then those kings, headed by Bhishma and Drona, with all
>   their troops, arose by thousands from the waters of Bhagirathi. There
>   were Virata and Drupada, with their sons and forces. There were the
>   sons of Draupadi and the son of Subhadra, with the Rakshasa
>   Ghatotkacha. There were Karna and Duryodhana, and the mighty
>   car-warrior Sakuni, and other children, endued with great strength, of
>   Dhritarashtra, headed by Dussasana. There were the son of Jarasandha,
>   and Bhagadatta and Jalasandha of great energy, and Bhurisravas, and
>   Sala, and Salya, and Vrishasena with his younger brother. ........
>   These and many others, who for their number cannot be conveniently
>   named, appeared on that occasion. All of them rose from the waters of
>   Bhagirathi, with resplendent bodies. Those kings appeared each clad in
>   that dress and equipt with that standard and that vehicle which he had
>   while fighting on the field. All of them were now robed in celestial
>   vestments and all had brilliant ear-rings. They were free from all
>   animosity and pride, and divested of wrath and jealousy. .... At that
>   time, through the puissance of his penances, the great ascetic, the
>   son of Satyavati, gratified with Dhritarashtra, gave him celestial
>   vision. Endued with celestial knowledge and strength, Gandhari of
>   great fame saw all her children as also all that had been slain in
>   battle.....'

Mahabharata, Asramavasika Parva Section XXXII

Comment: Excellent Find. Congratulations.

Comment: When I read this story, I was thinking how many of them will be aware of this story as it is really wonderful and not a famous one , nice to see people who have read this much .